# Passing specific sized arguments from C/C++ to ASM

Tags: c++, assembly, arguments

Due to technical situations I need to mix C++ and Assembly, passing numerical arguments and pointers from C++ to ASM. I've found many tutorials with very easy to understand examples and wrote some code to try passing arguments:

The assembly (NASM) code

```
; ASSEMBLY FUNCTION
global myFunction
global _myFunction
myFunction:
_myFunction:
   mov rax,rdi   ; 64 bits
   rol rax,2     ; 64 bits
ret
```

The C++ code

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" long long myFunction (long long);

int main (void) {
   long long x, y;
   x = 1;
   y = myFunction(x);
   printf("1<<2=%ll\n",y);
   return 0;
}
```

The compile and run output is this

```
[me@localhost ~]$ nasm -f elf64 test_asm.asm 
[me@localhost ~]$ g++ -o test test.cpp test_asm.o
[me@localhost ~]$ ./test 
1<<2=4
```

This 64-bit code is really useless, just used it to test passing arguments and it works as expected.

My doubts are:

1) How can I pass 32, 16 and 8-bit parameters on a 64-bit system? If I send smaller data will it be sent always over a 64-bit register and all I have to do is to use the required size register RAX, EAX, AX, AL (or other equivalent registers)?

2) If I return a result via the _AX register, how can I specify the size of the returned value? Or the C/C++ program automatically will copy the right register (RAX/EAX/AX/AL) according to the data type (int64, int32, int16, int8) of the returned data?

3) This example gets the parameter from a register. As far as I understood in other examples and posts, only the first (4) numerical arguments are passed via registers and the others on the stack. Other examples get the (1st) argument directly from the stack, right next to the return address. So... The WHOLE set of arguments is passed on the stack and (only) the first ones are copied to the registers? And, if I get the parameters from the stack, will they always be 64 or 32-bits size according to the system and the assembly program should take just the expected (64/32/16) bits size from the 64-bits value in the stack? I mean, if I send a 16-bits word as parameter, it will be always pushed as a 64-bits value and the assembly program should extract just the expected size from it?

4) In relationship with pointers, as far as I saw and understood in the examples, they are passed as a single value that is copied into an index register (like ESI), so... is it the data's offset and I should assume that it always resides into the current DATA SEGMENT as shown in all the examples I found?

Thanks in advance for your comments

Comment: Look up the calling convention used by your platform and write your assembly to conform to it?

Comment: Declare the function as returning `int16_t` or whatever you want.  That means the return value is in AX, not necessarily sign or zero-extended to fill RAX.  same for args.  Related: [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18133812) and [Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](//stackoverflow.com/a/36760539)

Comment: re: segmentation: x86-64 only supports a flat memory model, where CS/DS/ES/SS base=0.  All mainstream OSes already did this for 32-bit x86.  So offset = linear (virtual) address.  Pointers are just 64-bit integers.